# Pressure recovery from vorticity with Stokes-flow

Tags: pressure, navier-stokes, fluid-dynamics

I am solving Stokes-flow for thermal convection in the form of $\nabla^2 \textbf{u}+\nabla p = \textbf{f}$ and $\nabla\cdot\textbf{u} = 0$. With all free-slip boundary conditions I can turn this into vorticity formulation $\nabla^2\omega = \nabla \times\textbf{f}$, and recover velocity through $\nabla^2\textbf{u}= -\nabla\times\omega$. I'm not using stream function approach because it's for 3D. Now my question is, by having $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{f}$ it should be straight forward to calculate the dynamic pressure $p$ but I cannot figure it out... It should be possible with another Poisson somehow.

Any help is much appreciated!

Best,

Chris

Comment: Try taking the dot product of the Navier-Stokes equation and apply the continuity equation to the result, what do you get?